# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target in angular2

Tags: angular

I have created a service and trying to pass a parameter. When i try to define it with a parameter i get a compile error.

This works fine

```
createMovieCat(){
 /*     var headers = new Headers({"Access-Control-Request-Method" : "POST" ,  "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        const options = new RequestOptions( {headers: headers});
 */
        this._createURL = "http://localhost:8080/AdaRVM/api/movieCategory/create";
        this.emv  = new EmovieCat();
        this._http.post(this._createURL,JSON.stringify(this.emv)).subscribe(response =>{
            console.log(response.json());
        });
    }
```

When i add a parameter to the function i get compilation error as mentioned in the tittle. Seems simple but i can not see what is wrong, any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

```
createMovieCat(emv:EmovieCat){
 /*     var headers = new Headers({"Access-Control-Request-Method" : "POST" ,  "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        const options = new RequestOptions( {headers: headers});
 */
        this._createURL = "http://localhost:8080/AdaRVM/api/movieCategory/create";
       // this.emv  = new EmovieCat(); I removed this line 
        this._http.post(this._createURL,JSON.stringify(emv)).subscribe(response =>{
            console.log(response.json());
        });
    }
```

My model.

```
export class EmovieCat{

    id:String = "test";
    rev:String;
    dataModelVersion:number = 99;

}
```

Comment: Are you using the method anywhere in your code? Because the error states that you're trying to call a function without supplying all it's parameters.

Comment: Have you added this parameter in function call?

Comment: hmm i have a call without parameters in an old file but the editor did not warn me, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the methods with the parameter wherever you are using it,

```
createMovieCat(emv:EmovieCat)
```

say for example, if you are using inside a component

```
createMovieCat('PASSHERE');
```

Comment: You didn't state what's the error he was getting is all about and your example doesn't fit the implementation because EmovieCat isn't a string.

Comment: @cyrix i dint ask the user to pass a string, i just commented pass the correct parameter

Comment: I did indeed read the complete answer and stated my problems with it.